# Pandas Concat Different Sized DataFrame to End of Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Note: Contrived example. Please don't hate on forecasting and I don't need advice on it. This is strictly a Pandas how-to question.

**Example - One Solution**

I have two different sized DataFrames, one representing sales and one representing a forecast.

```
sales = pd.DataFrame({'sales':[5,3,5,6,4,4,5,6,7,5]})
forecast = pd.DataFrame({'forecast':[5,5.5,6,5]})
```

The forecast needs to be with the latest sales, which is at the end of the list of sales numbers [5, 6, 7, 5]. Other times, I might want it at other locations (please don't ask why, I just need it this way).

This works:

```
df = pd.concat([sales, forecast], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
df.columns = ['sales', 'forecast']  # Not necessary, making next command pretty
df.forecast = df.forecast.shift(len(sales) - len(forecast))
```

This gives me the desired outcome:

[image]

**Question**

What I want to know is: **Can I concatenate to the end of the sales data without performing the additional shift (the last command)**? I'd like to do this in one step instead of two. concat or something similar is fine, but I'd like to skip the shift.

I'm not hung up on having two lines of code. That's okay. I want a solution with the maximum possible performance. My application is sensitive to every millisecond we throw at it on account of huge volumes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if that is much faster but you could do

```
sales = pd.DataFrame({'sales':[5,3,5,6,4,4,5,6,7,5]})
forecast = pd.DataFrame({'forecast':[5,5.5,6,5]})

forecast.index = sales.index[-forecast.shape[0]:]
```

which gives

```
   forecast
6       5.0
7       5.5
8       6.0
9       5.0
```

and then simply

```
pd.concat([sales, forecast], axis=1)
```

yielding the desired outcome:

```
   sales  forecast
0      5       NaN
1      3       NaN
2      5       NaN
3      6       NaN
4      4       NaN
5      4       NaN
6      5       5.0
7      6       5.5
8      7       6.0
9      5       5.0
```

A one-line solution using the same idea, as mentioned by @Dark in the comments, would be:

```
pd.concat([sales, forecast.set_axis(sales.index[-len(forecast):], inplace=False)], axis=1)
```

giving the same output.

Comment: Make it a oneline `pd.concat([sales, forecast.set_axis(sales.index[-len(forecast):],inplace=False)],1)`. I have deleted my answer

Comment: @Dark: Thanks, I added it.

Comment: Impressive! I like that the index from the sales DF is copied to the forecast index in this operation. For those who need more description as I did initially, forecast.shape in this example, would give a tuple of (4,1) - 4 rows, 1 column. -forecast.shape[0] will get the 4 part of the tuple and the negative goes backwards in the DF. Therefore, we get the last 4 rows of the sales index and the forecast index thereby ends up with the same index as at the end of the sales DF. Concat then marries against the indexes. Thanks @Cleb. Very nice work.

Comment: I have a question here, what if forecast has more rows than sales?